# Default listview's onitemclick in drawerlayout not work

Tags: android, listview, drawerlayout, navigation-drawer

I'm new to Android programming. Recently I'm trying to build an application, which need drawerlayout. I followed the example in Android developer guide, it seems find but I found that I cannot set onItemClicklistener to the listView in the drawerLayout.

I tried to Google it and found nothing helpful (setfocusable(false) not work). My fragment contain a listview and a recyclerview. When I use debug mode, I found that the program cannot even enter the onItemClick method. Hope anyone can help!

```
  private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_enter, container, false);
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_main_content);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_add_question).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewQuestionActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item_main_drawer, mDrawerItem));
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new MainContentListAdapter(mList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getActivity(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("questionId", mList.get(position).getQuestionId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            })
    );

    return rootView;
}
```

And my XML file

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/button_click"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/black_semi_transparent"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorPressed="@color/black_semi_transparent"
        fab:fab_addButtonPlusIconColor="@color/half_black"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@style/menu_labels_style"
        fab:fab_labelsPosition="left"
        android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_add_question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/blue_semi_transparent"
            fab:fab_title="Raise Quesion"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/blue_semi_transparent_pressed"/>

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/button_nothing"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/blue_semi_transparent"
            fab:fab_title="nothing"
            fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/blue_semi_transparent_pressed"/>

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</RelativeLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:background="#111"/></android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

---

Update:

I found that the listView are always behind recyclerView, maybe that's the problem. However, I have tried bringToFront but seems doesn't work either. Any help?

Comment: Can you post your `list_item_main_drawer` xml? The root of that layout will need to be a class which implements Checkable, You also might want to take a look at [`NavigationView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) from the Design Support Library, which uses a menu resource and handles laying out the list for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
drawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("questionId", mList.get(position).getQuestionId());
                startActivity(intent);
    }
            });
```

Instead of:

```
mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());
```

Comment: Actually the startActivity event is handled by another listener (RecyclerView).

Comment: What exactly you want to do? you want to start another activity when a user clicks on an item in your drawerList, right? and depending on what item was clicked an activity should start accordingly.

Comment: No, the list in the drawer will call another function to update current data and refresh the current fragment according to updated data.        While when user click the item in recyclerView, he will enter another activity which display a detailed version of that item.

Comment: I found that the listView is always behind recyclerView, this maybe the reason. But I don't know how to fix that. Really appreciate if you can help.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I get time for coding only on weekends. are you still stuck on it or is it resolved?

Comment: Oh, thank you for still considering this problem. The problem is mainly because I lay fragment two times therefore the drawerlayout is hidden below the recycler view. (Due to mistake in using fragment manager)